# Dealing with Selenium tests that fail occasionally during automated deployment

Tags: automated-tests, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

We have a C#/ASP .Net web application that is built and deployed by the build server (Jenkins). One of the build steps before the automated deployment is ensuring that all automated tests pass -- including functional tests we have using Selenium 2 WebDriver and NUnit.

The problem: Sometimes these tests fail randomly. They will succeed for 100 builds and then one just fails. They fail for various reasons -- a .Click() event is just ignored, element can't be found, IE has a bad day, etc. We have an AJAX heavy web app and so we depend heavily on WebDriverWaits but we always take this into account while writing tests, and like I said the tests do pass most of the time.

What are some ways to avoid or fix this problem? A couple that came to my mind:

- Accept a certain number of failures (seems like a bad idea)
- Rerun test failures?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't like either of the suggestions that you mention, but I admit to having used them occasionally.  The best thing to do is to make sure that when there is a seemingly "random" failure to do everything you can to get all of the data about why it really failed.  Was it an environment issue?  Did some other process on the machine interfere with the tests?  Was it a timing issue that only appears when the site loads excruciatingly slow, or blazing fast?

One thing that you might try is soak testing your automated tests.  Run each one 100+ times on the same build and same environment (so you can rule those out as potential failure points) and find the ones that fail occasionally.  See if they fail in the same place or in different places.  Generally, when you go through this exercise you'll find some tests that really are a little bit flaky and you can remove them from the daily run until they are fixed.  You could even include a soak as a check-in criteria for any automated test case.

Another useful thing I have found that helped me get to the bottom of some of the seemingly random failures was taking screenshots on failure.  Often you can see that other windows or dialogs were popped up causing the browsers not to be able to be in the forefront, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I like the 'soak testing' idea -- after doing (and taking screenshots) that I saw some of the tests always fail at the same spot so I'll be taking a closer look at them.

Comment: @Kryptic Interesting. I'm dealing with something similar myself. Are there any patterns you remember finding during that closer look at those flaky tests?

Answer (score 5):

Of the two, I would prefer to rerun test failures, or rather, on test failure, retry the tests.

If you accept a certain number of test failures, then you get into problems about which tests are allowed to fail. You would have to have two sets of tests, some which are allowed to fail, some which are not.

For rerunning, I'm no expert on testing with NUnit, but you could have the tests themselves manage the retry. In JUnit, you can introduce a rule so that if a test fails, it would retry a maximum of 3 times. This would probably avoid most of the problems you're having. I don't know how to do this in NUnit, but see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8301639/1836) to [How to Re-run failed JUnit tests immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295100/how-to-re-run-failed-junit-tests-immediately). This will give you the general idea.

Comment: The only caution I would give here is that re-running test failures could sometimes mean that an intermittent product failure gets missed.  At the very least log the failure and if the retry succeeds, you can still do the automated deployment, but at least flag the failure and investigate it.

Comment: Thanks, it was kind of awkward to do in NUnit but I managed to add this in until I debug the tests as a short-term solution