# How can Spock be made to retry failed Geb tests?

Tags: grails, groovy, spock, geb

I have functional tests for a Grails app which use Geb and Spock.  Occasionally, a functional test will fail for timeouts or other sporadic behavior. In previous projects using TestNG, I'd have a retryAnalyzer just trigger a retry during test execution to see if it fails both times (and then fail for real).

How do I get Spock to retry a failed test?

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is a year old, but we've been having the same problem. Following Peter's suggestion, I created a Spock extension (https://github.com/anotherchrisberry/spock-retry).

If you have a base specification (which was our case), you can just add a `@RetryOnFailure` annotation to it:

```
@RetryOnFailure
class BaseFunctionalSpec extends Specification {
    //    all tests will execute up to two times before failing
}
```

Or, you can add it to a specific feature:

```
class SomeSpec extends Specification {

    @RetryOnFailure(times=3)
    void 'test something that fails sporadically'() {
        // will execute test up to three times before failing
    }
}
```

Comment: I look forward to giving this a try.

Comment: this is the best extension

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to write a little JUnit rule (for example something like https://gist.github.com/897229) or Spock extension. You'd probably have to live with some limitations like the same spec instance being reused and JUnit just reporting a single test, but hopefully nothing that rules out the approach altogether. (One thing that comes to mind is that mocking might not work.) In a future version of Spock, repeating a test (or its building blocks) will likely become a first-class concept, doing away with these limitations.

Comment: I've finally gone down the junit rule route, and added a class similar to the one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295100/how-to-re-run-failed-junit-tests-immediately  . I put println statements around the base.evaluate() call, and I can tell my rule is being run, but I'm finding that it always *returns*, and I never see a Throwable thrown, even on failure.  Is there another way to tell the test failed?