# Re-run failed Test Script 'completely' using JUnit

Tags: junit

I found some solution to rerun failed @Test in this forum at [How to Re-run failed JUnit tests immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295100/how-to-re-run-failed-junit-tests-immediately). In my case i execute the test from command line. And i want to rerun the complete test if it fails. Given below is my Test Script template and i want to rerun everything (from start to end) if it fails

```
@BeforeClass
public static void Start(){
...
}

@Test
public void Test_One(){
...
}

@Test
public void Test_Two(){
...
}

@AfterClass
public static void End(){
...
}
```

I will get to know in End() method if my test script has failed. If it fails, i would like to run everything like

```
@BeforeClass
@Test (all @Test)
@AfterClass
```

Is it possible with JUnit? 
I am not sure if the template that i am using is correct :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JanakiL,
It is a very good question. I tried to find some solution but i didn't manage to find clean solution for this task.
I can only propose to do some workaround that eventually will work. 
So, in order to re-run suite you need to do following steps:

1. You need to  create @ClassRule in order to execute whole suite.
   All Suite you can retry using following code:

   public class Retrier implements TestRule{

   ```
   private int retryCount;
   private int failedAttempt = 0;
       @Override
   public Statement apply(final Statement base,
           final Description description) {
       return new Statement() {
           @Override
           public void evaluate() throws Throwable {               

               base.evaluate();                 
               while (retryNeeded()){
                   log.error( description.getDisplayName() + " failed");
                   failedAttempt++;                    

               }

           }
   ```

   }

retryNeeded() – method that determines whether you need to do retry or not

This will retry all tests in your suite. Very important thing that retry will go after   @AfterClass method.

In case you need to have “green build” after successful retry you need to write a bunch of another gloomy code.

1. You need to create @Rule that will not allow “publish” failed result. As example:

`public class FailedRule extends TestWatcher {`

```
@Override
public Statement apply(final Statement base, final Description description) {
         return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                List<Throwable> errors = new ArrayList<Throwable>();
                try {

                    base.evaluate();

                } catch (AssumptionViolatedException e) {
                    log.error("", e.getMessage());

                    if (isLastRun()) {
                        throw e;
                    }

                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    log.error("", t.getMessage());                  
                    if (isLastRun()) {
                        throw t;
                    }
                }
            };

        };
}   
}
```

isLastRun() – methods to verify whether it is last run and fail test only in case ir is last run.

Only last retry needs to be published to mark you test failed and build “red”.
3.  And finally in your test class you need do register two rules:

```
@Rule
public FailedRule ruleExample = new FailedRule ();
@ClassRule 
public static Retrier retrier = new Retrier (3);
```

In the Retrier  you can pass count of attempts to retry.

I hope that  somebody could suggest better solution !

Comment: Thanks user1459144 for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse, in the Junit view, you have a button "ReRun Tests - Failures First"

You can also see this answer: [How to Re-run failed JUnit tests immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295100/how-to-re-run-failed-junit-tests-immediately)

Comment: I run my test scripts from command line. So I can't use eclipse to re-run. I did refer the post which you have mentioned. Like i mentioned my earlier post, that link discusses how to rerun failed @Test alone. But i want to run BeforeClass > Test > AfterClass.

Answer (score 0):

More flexible solution is to write custom runner.
I described this answer in the following post:

[How to Re-run failed JUnit tests immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295100/how-to-re-run-failed-junit-tests-immediately/20762914#20762914)