# Trying to run retries on before() Method before failing a test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, integration-testing

I have an unstable ENV which im running JUnit tests on.

Many tests fails on `before()` method because connection/network/non test related issues and I want to add a feature that retries a before method - before failing the test completely.

I've added the code snippet but im not sure this is the best way/practice to do so...

```
//hold the max number of before attempts
final private int retries = 3;
//will count number of retries accrued
private int retrieCounter = 0 ;

@Before
public void before() {
    try {
        //doing stuff that may fail due to network / other issues that are not relevant to the test
        setup = new Setup(commonSetup);
        server = setup.getServer();
        agents = setup.getAgents();
        api = server.getApi();
        setup.reset();
    }
    //if before fails in any reason
    catch (Exception e){
        //update the retire counter
        retrieCounter++;
        //if we max out the number of retries exit with a runtime exception
        if (retrieCounter > retries)
            throw new RuntimeException("not working and the test will stop!");
        //if not run the before again
        else this.before();
    }

}
```

Comment: except for refactoring this to be a loop and not recursion, your next best option would be to write your own test runner and use that with the @runwith annotation.

Comment: I think this would be much better done as a loop rather than recursion. Also, if the environment changes with time, consider putting a sleep call in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [TestRule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/TestRule.java) for this, please look at my answer to [How to Re-run failed JUnit tests immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295100/how-to-re-run-failed-junit-tests-immediately/8301639#8301639). This should do what you want. If you use the Retry rule defined in that answer, this will actually re-execute the before() if it throws an exception:

```
public class RetryTest {
  @Rule
  public Retry retry = new Retry(3);

  @Before
  public void before() {
    System.err.println("before");
  }

  @Test
  public void test1() {
  }

  @Test
  public void test2() {
      Object o = null;
      o.equals("foo");
  }
}
```

This produces:

```
before
test2(junit_test.RetryTest): run 1 failed
before
test2(junit_test.RetryTest): run 2 failed
before
test2(junit_test.RetryTest): run 3 failed
test2(junit_test.RetryTest): giving up after 3 failures
before
```

Comment: Your solution retries the test body.  It does not recover in any way from a failure in setup methods annotated with Before, which the actual question.