# how to run failed test cases in selenium webDriver

Tags: junit, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am new to Selenium, learning about Selenium, recently I came across a question in Selenium that, if we are executing 20 test cases in that, if 13 passed and 7 failed, how can we run only  that 7 failed test cases in Selenium? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Re-run failed JUnit tests immediately?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295100/how-to-re-run-failed-junit-tests-immediately)

Comment: A simple Google search will give you many options on how to rerun only failed tests.