# Rerun failed test with Jbehave and WebDriver, Java

Tags: java, junit, webdriver, jbehave

I want to rerun failed end-to-end tests. I'm using Jbehave and WebDriver, Java. Currently I'm using Maven but going to migrate to Gradle. 
Is there any solution?

Comment: Why can't you relaunch the tests? 
Also, most of the IDE allow you , for a set of launched test whose have been launche by the IDE , to rerun only the one who have failed.

Comment: I need to relaunch them automatically during test run on Jenkins.

Comment: Actually I got a good recommendation in JBehave user group "You can throw a RestartingStoryFailure or RestartingScenarioFailure.  "

Comment: If I understand, you want to relaunch a test who have failed, with the same code? Test aren't supposed to have the same result launch after launch?

Answer (score 0):

I think JBehave is able to run JUnit stories, and so, you might use a JUnit `@Rule` to implement the retries mechanism. Take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295100/how-to-re-run-failed-junit-tests-immediately).