# How re-run failed test in Espresso? - brainstorming

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, android-espresso

I am trying to figure out, how to re-run failed tests with usage of Espresso. I think it's a bit more complicated from common JUnit test case as you need to restore status in your app from before test start.

My approach is to create my own ActivityTestRule so I just copied whole code from this class and named it MyActivityTestRule.

In case of instrumentation tests rule will also need information of how we want to start our activity. I prefer to launch it myself rather than have environment to do it for me. So for example:

```
    @Rule
    public MyActivityTestRule<ActivityToStartWith> activityRule = new MyActivityTestRule<>(
           ActivityToStartWith.class, true, false
    );
```

So I also launch my activity in @Before annotation method:

```
   @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        activityRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
    }
```

And make clean up in @After annotation method:

```
    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        cleanUpDataBaseAfterTest();
        returnToStartingActivity(activityRule);
    }
```

Those methods - setUp(), tearDown() are essential to be called before/after each test run - to ensure the app state during the test start is correct.

---

Inside MyActivityTestRule I did few modifications so far. First thing is change of apply method from:

```
    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement base, Description description) {
       return new ActivityStatement(super.apply(base, description));
    }
```

It's a but unknown thing for me, as ActivityStatement placed in ActivityTestRule has super.apply method so it also wraps test statement in UiThreadStatement:

```
public class UiThreadStatement extends Statement {
    private final Statement mBase;
    private final boolean mRunOnUiThread;

    public UiThreadStatement(Statement base, boolean runOnUiThread) {
        mBase = base;
        mRunOnUiThread = runOnUiThread;
    }

    @Override
    public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
        if (mRunOnUiThread) {
            final AtomicReference<Throwable> exceptionRef = new AtomicReference<>();
            getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        mBase.evaluate();
                    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                        exceptionRef.set(throwable);
                    }
                }
            });
            Throwable throwable = exceptionRef.get();
            if (throwable != null) {
                throw throwable;
            }
        } else {
            mBase.evaluate();
        }
    }
}
```

No mather what I do with my tests I can never create case mRunOnUiThread boolean to be true. It will be true if within my test cases, tests with annotation @UiThreadTest will be present - or that's what I understood from code. It never happens though, I don't use anything like that so I decided to ignore this UiThreadStatement and change MyActivityTestRule to:

```
    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement base, Description description) {
       return new ActivityStatement(base);
    }
```

And my test cases run without any problem. Thanks to that all I have left - that wraps around mBase.evaluate() is:

```
private class ActivityStatement extends Statement {

    private final Statement mBase;

    public ActivityStatement(Statement base) {
        mBase = base;
    }

    @Override
    public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
        try {
            if (mLaunchActivity) {
                mActivity = launchActivity(getActivityIntent());
            }
            mBase.evaluate();
        } finally {
            finishActivity();
            afterActivityFinished();
        }
    }
}
```

In general launchActivity will be called only if I set in the 3rd parameter of ActivityTestRule constructor value true. But I launch tests by myself in setUp() so it never happens.

From what I understood mBase.evaluate() runs my code inside @Test annotation method. It also stops the test case during throwable being thrown. That means I can catch it and restart it - like proposed there:
 [How to Re-run failed JUnit tests immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295100/how-to-re-run-failed-junit-tests-immediately)

And okay I did something like that:

```
 public class ActivityRetryStatement extends Statement {

        private final Statement mBase;
        private final int MAX_RUNS = 2;

        public ActivityRetryStatement(Statement base) {
            mBase = base;
        }

        @Override
        public void evaluate() throws Throwable {

            Throwable throwable = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RUNS; i++) {

                try {
                    mBase.evaluate();
                    // if you reach this lane that means evaluate passed
                    // and you don't need to do the next run
                    break;
                } catch (Throwable t) {

                    // save first throwable if occurred
                    if (throwable == null) {
                        throwable = t;
                    }

                    // my try that didn't work
                    launchActivity(testInitialIntent);
                    // I've returned test to starting screen but
                    // mBase.envaluate() didn't make it run again

                    // it would be cool now to:
                    // - invoke @After
                    // - finish current activity
                    // - invoke @Before again and start activity
                    // - mBase.evaluate() should restart @Test on activity started again by @Before
                } 
            }

            finishActivity();
            afterActivityFinished();

            // if 1st try fail but 2nd passes inform me still that there was error
            if (throwable != null) {
                throw throwable;
            }
        }
    }
```

So those comments in catch block are parts I don't know how to do. I tried to perform launchActivity on intent I used in setUp() to run the test for the 1st time. But mBase.evaluate() didn't make it react (test case didn't go again) - nothing happened + it wouldn't really save me there I think. I lacked some initiations I do in @SetUp, it wasn't called again. I would really like to find a way how to properly restart whole test lifecycle @Before @Test @After over again. Maybe some call on Instrumentation or TestRunner from code.

Any thoughts about how it could be done?

Comment: got any solutions?

Comment: If by any coincidence you are using firebase test labs you can use a flag "--num-flaky-test-attempts 2" (to retry twice) for that. Baking a repeat behaviour into the tests themselves has proven too flaky/difficult to troubleshoot for me so I would discourage from that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista library for rerunning failed tests.

You can see more details about dealing with flaky tests here: https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista#dealing-with-flaky-tests

Answer (score 0):

The answer is super simple. Just make sure you upgrade your espresso tests to Junit 4, and then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8301639/636733)

Comment: I tried to put `evaluate()` in loop but what happened -> @Test code block was executing again, but device didn't react. Did it work for you ON Espresso - not common Junit tests? (I am using Junit ver 4.12)

Comment: Yep I implemented this in our Espresso tests and it worked just fine. It's probably the way you are setting up your tests that's the issue. Can you post a gist of an example test that also includes the Retry rule as implemented in the answer I linked to?

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for that information. Currently I am really busy with work but I will for sure check it asap because I am very interested in that and I will give you feedback if it worked or provide some code so we can check what I am doing wrong :)