# jenkins pipeline rerun option for only failed tests

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have setup jenkins declarative pipeline and I have setup choice parameters to run tests like

```
parameters {
        choice choices: ['job_1', 'job_2'], description: 'Select job to run.', name: 'JOB_NAME'

        gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin/.*', defaultValue: 'master', name: 'BRANCH', selectedValue: 'DEFAULT'
    }
```

But I have lot of tests and I for second run I want to run only failed tests in pipeline. Is there way I can have choice parameter or checkbox or any other way to provide option to run only failed tests.

Answer (score 0):

It is always recommended to rerun the complete test suite after fixing the issues with the previous execution. Hence there is no standard solution to this problem. 
However, there is a workaround and it is already available on Stack Overflow 
[rerun flaky JUnit test in case they failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37918522/rerun-flaky-junit-test-in-case-they-failed)

Comment: This is not what the author asked. He is asking about rerun flake tests with declarative pipeline.