# maven -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount with parameterized tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, surefire, junitparams

I want to re-run failed tests with maven. I'm using surefire.rerunFailingTestsCount for this:

```
mvn '-Dtest=LoginTest#loginAsValidUser' '-Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=1'clean test
```

However, after tests fail, they are not found again by junit when trying to re-run:

```
org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter.initializationError(org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter)
  Run 1: Filter.initializationError »  No tests found matching Method loginAsValidUser[...
  Run 2: Filter.initializationError »  No tests found matching Method loginAsValidUser[...
  Run 3: Filter.initializationError »  No tests found matching Method loginAsValidUser[...
```

According to [maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test), test method can be also indicated with [*], so I tried

```
mvn '-Dtest=LoginTest#loginAsValidUser[*]' -Dsurefire.rerunFailingTestsCount=1 clean test
```

and different variations of specifying test class/methods name, but outcome is the same.
Any ideas what is causing this?

maven-surefire plugin version is 2.19.1, junit version is 4.12, junitparams version is 1.0.5.

Test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class LoginTest {

    @Test
    @FileParameters(value = "src/main/resources/login_data.csv")
    @TestCaseName("{method}[{index}]")
    public void loginAsValidUser(String username, String password) {
        //test
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I found [surefire bugreport](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1146) for similar situation but that was fixed. I took sample code that demonstrated the bug and run it, worked well. Then I changed runner to junitparams runner and got same error a described above. I guess this may be a bug with runner, so I opened [issue](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams/issues/86) on their github.

Comment: Did you try it without the ' around the commandline parameters?

Comment: The same doesn't work for me with `WebDriverRunner`. Have you had any progress on the issue?

Comment: @AlexeySubach I eventually gave up and did an implementation based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295100/how-to-re-run-failed-junit-tests-immediately)