# Junit Rule with PowerMockito : ClassNotPreparedException

Tags: junit, mockito, powermockito, junit-rule, mockstatic

I working on testing some static classes using PowerMockito, and sometimes the test fail, in order to overcame this issue a create a [customize JUnit Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8301639/6725850)  to re-run the failure tests. The rule works fine but whenever the test is re-executed , it's fail again but this time at the instruction `mockStatic(StaticClass.class)` which throw the exception `org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException`. 
Why the @PrepareForTest is executed only at the first run but not when the test is re-run.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was caused by PowerMock when he creat a deep clone of my rules. To overcome this problem I used JUnit rule chain :

```
RuleChain.outerRule((base, description) -> {
        try {
            final FrameworkMethod method = new FrameworkMethod(
                    description.getTestClass().getMethod(description.getMethodName()));
            return (new PowerMockRule()).apply(base, method, this);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }).around(myRetryRule).around(otherRules).....
```

A more generale soulution for this problem is proposed here [MergedRule](https://bitbucket.org/anydoby/gcloud-storage-emulator/src/2c73efd0df7d81670f2cd3f7561d27efc61bdf7e/src/main/java/com/anydoby/gcloud/MergedRule.java?at=master#MergedRule.java-16,22), [2](https://bitbucket.org/anydoby/gcloud-storage-emulator/src/2c73efd0df7d81670f2cd3f7561d27efc61bdf7e/src/main/java/com/anydoby/gcloud/GCloudStorageRule.java?at=master#GCloudStorageRule.java-88,105,108,111,571), [3](https://bitbucket.org/anydoby/gcloud-storage-emulator/src/2c73efd0df7d81670f2cd3f7561d27efc61bdf7e/src/test/java/com/anydoby/gcloud/GCloudStorageRuleWithOtherRulesTest.java?at=master#GCloudStorageRuleWithOtherRulesTest.java-7,14).